# jQuery AJAX call issue - it won't open my localhost file

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, localhost

I am running MAMP (apache) for a localhost as I want to load a file from my c drive. I point the port to 8888 and the web server to my C:\mail.

I am running a Knockout.js app - the index.html file.

From my viwemodel, here's my jQuery Ajax call to get a file on my server but I get a custom error alert. Error encountered ---> XHR status: 0. / Error thrown: . / XHR response Text: . / XHR response XML:  undefined. / Text status: error

```
    $.ajax(
    {
      type: "GET",                              
      dataType: "json",                         
      url: "http://localhost:8888/Inbox.json", 
      success: function(response)
      {                         
        alert("data.json file loaded succesfully!");                              
      }, 
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error encountered ---> XHR status: " + jqXHR.status + ". / Error thrown: " + errorThrown.toString() + ". / XHR response Text: " + jqXHR.responseText + ". / XHR response XML:  " + jqXHR.responseXML + ". / Text status: " + textStatus);
      }      
    });
```

In the console tab, I get: index.html:1 Failed to load http://localhost:8888/Inbox.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I can point the Chrome browser to http://localhost:8888/Inbox.json and it opens the file:

[image]

If I just change the url to contain 2 colons: http:://localhost:8888/Inbox.json"
I get a custom error alert:

Error encountered ---> XHR status: 0. / Error thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': **Invalid URL**. / XHR response Text: undefined. / XHR response XML:  undefined. / Text status: error

In the console tab, i get no messages.

Here's the MAMP screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My C:\mail folder:

[image]

Comment: What is the open URL for the current page in the browser which executes this JavaScript code?

Comment: file:///C:/Dans/Work%202/Tech/Web%20Dev/Javascript%20and%20jQuery/Knockout.js/Tutorials/SPA/index.html

Comment: Then that's the problem.  You're trying to use AJAX to access an entirely different server, and the Same Origin Policy restricts that.  Instead of "running" your HTML file from the file system, open it from its server URL on your local web server.  Then it'll be `localhost` trying to access `localhost`, which is perfectly fine.  In general, keep your web development on a web server, even locally.  The file system is a poor substitute for a web server.

Comment: You are experiencing a CORS error. You cant go cross domain on an AJAX call without specifically enabling this on your host server for the calling domain.

Comment: @ David I copied the my code files from my C drive folder to my C:\mail folder which the localhost points to. I double-click on the index file. The URL now is: file:///C:/mail/index.html and I get the custom error: Error encountered ---> XHR status: 0. / Error thrown: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL. / XHR response Text: undefined. / XHR response XML:  undefined. / Text status: error

Comment: @Korgrue New to this, so how do I do that using MAMP?

Comment: @user3020047: `"I double-click on the index file."` - Ya, stop doing that.  Navigate to your file's *URL*, don't open it *from the file system*.  The problem isn't which *folder* the file is in, the problem is that you're opening it *as a file* instead of as a web page.

Comment: "If I just change the url to contain 2 colons: http::" er, why would that help? It's not a valid syntax to specify the protocol.

Comment: @David. OK..I understand now. I changed all src references in the index file to point to the localhost. I entered this into my URL http://localhost:8888/index.html. It now loads my file. thanks.